# How do you increase the size of lists inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to figure out how to increase the size of the lists inside a list of lists. For example `[[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]` and want to be able to add 1 more onto it so it is `[[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]`. The numbers are just to show i want them to now have a new element in each.

Comment: They may be inside another list, but that doesn't change the fact that each of them is a list, and has an append function.

Comment: Research before asking please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for-loop and `.append()`.

```
>>> L = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> for sublist in L:
...     sublist.append(5)
...
>>> L
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```